# No me sale este resultado Imprimir “Resultado: ”, 2 * i C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-8.0

Hola que tal soy nuevo es C#

```
i = -1
```

Mientras i <= 7 Hacer
i = i + 2
Imprimir “Resultado: ”, 2 * i
Repetir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte mas fácilmente y evita poner código como imagen.

Si entiendo bien que es lo que necesitas, la respuesta seria asi:

```
public void Respuestas()
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 7)
    {
        i = i + 2;
        int resultado = 2 * i;
        Console.WriteLine("Resultado: " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte! sin embargo, en estos casos con preguntas tan mal planteadas (y casi sin sentido) recomendamos no responder, ya que las mismas suelen terminar cerradas

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi, lo tendré en cuenta!